# Insert a line break (Alt+Enter) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro for relacing a word with another one in Excel.

```
Call CharactersReplace(xRg, "Test1", "Test2", True)
```

It is working nicely but I want to do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the cell of Excel (instead of Test2).

Literally I want to do the line wrap within the cell.

Example:

```
From: Hey How are you? Test1 Bla Bla
To: Hey How are you?
Bla Bla
```

There is a code on VBA to do it? I tried to do CHA(10) etc. but they are not working.

Comment: Did you try CHR()? There's also vbCrLf which might work.

Comment: chr()? what? @MichaelMurphy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `vbLf` or `Chr(10)` is the equivalent of a line break whithin a cell. So the following should work:

```
Call CharactersReplace(xRg, "Test1", vbLf, True)
```

Also make sure that `.WrapText` of that cell is `True`.

eg: `Range("A1").WrapText = True` otherwise you will insert a line break but won't see it.